# How to debug AMI CLI commands?

Tags: amazon-ses, amazon-ami

I'm trying to update an IAM (SES) policy from the AWS CLI (I don't have access to the GUI).
However, I'm stuck in debugging the following.

Even if I just try to put the policy I've just gotten, I get an error:

```
$ aws iam get-policy-version --policy arn:aws:iam::627566394409:policy/Allow_only_email_from_jsonar_com_and_jsonar_public_IP_address --version-id v87 > /tmp/tmp.tmp

$ aws iam put-user-policy --user-name "user.name" --policy-name "Allow_only_email_from_jsonar_com_and_jsonar_public_IP_address" --policy-document "/tmp/tmp.tmp"

An error occurred (MalformedPolicyDocument) when calling the PutUserPolicy operation: Syntax errors in policy.
$
```

Any suggestion how can I debug the above?

### Edit 1:

```
$ cat /tmp/tmp.tmp
{
    "PolicyVersion": {
        "Document": {
            "Version": "2012-10-17",
            "Statement": [
                {
                    "Effect": "Deny",
                    "Action": [
                        "ses:SendEmail",
                        "ses:SendRawEmail"
                    ],
                    "Resource": "*",
                    "Condition": {
                        "NotIpAddress": {
                            "aws:SourceIp": [
                                "96.53.84.10",
                                "54.147.198.250",
                                "40.83.166.244",
                                "34.237.100.184",
                                "34.196.101.5",
                                "100.0.210.23",
                                "18.191.175.97",
                                "3.220.230.218",
                                "34.238.138.152",
                                "52.27.144.48",
                                "18.236.224.102",
                                "54.212.142.224",
                                "34.255.246.43",
                                "18.237.251.118",
                                "52.43.37.137",
                                "13.57.28.215",
                                "3.18.150.216",
                                "18.236.244.218",
                                "54.244.159.89",
                                "34.220.115.94",
                                "52.89.73.234",
                                "18.237.168.166",
                                "34.221.190.87",
                                "54.201.162.123",
                                "52.10.179.15",
                                "18.191.42.195",
                                "18.237.208.235",
                                "52.43.182.218",
                                "34.217.119.154",
                                "54.149.171.228",
                                "18.218.128.38",
                                "34.208.186.182",
                                "54.202.170.224",
                                "54.190.91.35",
                                "34.222.80.194",
                                "54.187.165.14",
                                "34.221.50.106",
                                "35.165.182.15",
                                "107.20.3.223",
                                "3.91.206.6"
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "VersionId": "v87",
        "IsDefaultVersion": true,
        "CreateDate": "2019-09-26T00:08:47Z"
    }
}
$
```

Comment: You should share what `/tmp/tmp.tmp` contains.

Comment: See 'Edit 1', @ceejayoz. However, since `/tmp/tmp.tmp` is created by `aws iam get-policy-version`, I assume it's correctly formatted.